Python tkinter close first window while opening second window
I'm trying to close the first window as the second window opens. Both windows close, or the first window closes and the second window never opens.
This question has a similar problem but was solved by addressing the imported libraries: Tkinter is opening a second windows when the first one is closing
This question also has a similar problem, but the solution keeps all windows active/open all the time, but withdraws the windows from view/user interaction when they are not being used.  I want a solution without keeping 23 windows open at the same time. Python tkinter cloase first window while opening second window
I don't want to keep multiple windows open at the same time. What I am asking in this question is a MWE.  So I've included only two windows in this question.  My actual application has 23 windows in a tree-like structure.
quit and destroy both close the mainloop.  Ideally, I'd use one mainloop and open and close windows as I need them rather than close one mainloop and sequentially open 22 other mainloops.
Here's my code, which was taken from here https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-toplevel/
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Window(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)


        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.title('Toplevel Window')

        ttk.Button(self,
                text='Close',
                command=self.destroy).pack(expand=True)


class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__()
        self.root = root

        root.geometry('300x200')
        root.title('Main Window')

        # place a button on the root window
        ttk.Button(root,
                text='Open a window',
                command=self.open_window).pack(expand=True)

    def open_window(self):
        window = Window(self.root)
        window.grab_set()
        self.root.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()

I added in self.destroy() in the function def open_window(self).  I also tried root.quit().  Both will close both windows.
I adapted this script so that class App takes root as an argument, rather than being a subclass of tk.Tk.

If you want to keep .mainloop() running, there should be at least one instance of Tk().  So destroying root will terminate .mainloop().
For your case, in order to keep .mainloop() running after destroying root, Window should inherit from Tk instead of Toplevel:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.title('Second Window')

        ttk.Button(self,
                text='Close',
                command=self.destroy).pack(expand=True)


class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__()
        self.root = root

        root.geometry('300x200')
        root.title('Main Window')

        # place a button on the root window
        ttk.Button(root,
                text='Open a window',
                command=self.open_window).pack(expand=True)

    def open_window(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        window = Window()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()


your super init should give a parameter (root).
maybe you should try it because what you've done seems fine.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
